# Find a zero of a function: $f(x)= x+\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: graphing-functions

Find a zero of a function: $$f(x)= x+\sqrt{1-x}$$

What I did: $$x+\sqrt{1-x}=0$$

$$\sqrt{1-x}=-x$$

$$1-x=x^2$$

$$0=x^2+x-1$$

$$x_{1}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}  $$
$$x_{2}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}  $$

But in solutions says there's only one zero of this function: $$x_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}  $$

And I can't figure out why? The domain is $(-\infty,1]$ and both $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ "lie inside" that domain.

It can be even seen from the graph that this function has only one zero $(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2},0)$:

[image]

Comment: As $\sqrt {1-x}\ge0,$ we must have $x\le0$

Comment: $x \le 1$ @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw, I mean $x$ can not be positive as $x+\sqrt{1-x}=0$

Comment: We have $\sqrt{1-x}=-x$, so definitely $x$ is negative, because $-x$ is a positive square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line $\sqrt{1-x}=-x$. On the left hand side you have always something positive, but this has to be equal with $-x$, so $x$ must be negative.

Comment: comments were faster.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you square during your steps, you are liable to gain extraneous solutions, so you have to go back and make sure that the solutions work.

Comment: $1-x_2$ is positive!

Comment: @sranthrop Whoops, I mean $x_1$. OP had it listed two ways in various parts of his question.

Comment: $1-x_1$ is also positive ;)

Comment: @sranthrop A ha... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see that in the $f(x)$ values for $x \ge 1$ are not defined .